# Repository with entities not including linked entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern, repository-design

i'm trying the following.
I have a repository that returns a list of Deposits.
I also want to get the entities that are related to the Deposit-entity (i.e. contract)

I'm not getting it done. 
Can anyone help me?

This is my repository :

```
public class DepositRepository : Repository<Deposit, int>, IDepositRepository
{
    public DepositRepository(IComPostSession session) : base(session) { }

    public Deposit GetById(int id)
    {
        return this.Query.SingleOrDefault(deposit => deposit.Id == id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Deposit> GetAllOpenDeposits()
    {
        IEnumerable<Deposit> deposits = this.Query.ToList();

        return deposits;
    }
}
```

My Deposit-entity looks as follows:

```
public class Deposit : IEntity<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DepositDate { get; set; }
    public int EnvelopeTypeCarrierClassificationId { get; set; }
    public int CarrierCustomerContractVersionId { get; set; }

    public EnvelopeTypeCarrierClassification EnvelopeTypeCarrierClassificiation { get; set; }
    public CarrierCustomerContractVersion CarrierCustomerContractVerision { get; set; }
}
```

So when i get my list of deposits, i also want the linked EnvelopeTypeCarrierClassification and the linked CarrierCustomerContractVersion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Include` will help you.

Change your `GetById` to

```
public Deposit GetById(int id)
{
    return this.Query
               .Include(p => p.EnvelopeTypeCarrierClassificiation)
               .Include(p => p.CarrierCustomerContractVersion)
               .SingleOrDefault(deposit => deposit.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: I tried looking for the Include allready, but I don't have it. There is no Include-method.

Comment: @BartSchelkens, try adding this namespace `using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice that I hadn't included that namespace.

Answer (score 0):

There are to possibilities. In your DataContext Enable **LazyLoading** which loads your linked object on demand, or if you want to do it yourself you have to use the Include() if the EntityCollection u use.

**Example**

```
myDataContext.MyObjectEntities.Include("MyLinkedEntity").ToList();
```

[ObjectQuery.Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx)